# how to activate Iad feature to iphone App

Tags: ios4

hi 
       i have worked in simple app in which i implement iad feature but i don't know how to activate iad feature to iphone app
 plz out of snippet  please give step to activate iad network and its functionality .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the iAD Framework and also enable it for your app on iTunes Connect.

Then try the following...

```
iAdBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 245.0, 768.0, 66.0)];


        if(&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil)
            portrait = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        else
            portrait = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;

        if(&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape != nil)
            landscape = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
        else
            landscape = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;

        iAdBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:landscape, nil];

        iAdBanner.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        iAdBanner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        iAdBanner.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:iAdBanner];

        iAdBanner.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: hi  lee ihave implement all the code but problem is that  i need step to activate iad feature from  itune process

Comment: Login to iTunes connect, can go to the Manage Applications section.  In the app you can manage iAd and enable it in there.  You have to have an update pending to enable it.

Comment: Yes, that code will display ads.  Suggest you look at the Apple docs and look in the console and implement the delegate callbacks also. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html

Comment: can signing iad advertisement  contract and enable iAd network  need to pay extra money on app strore because i dont have any idea about this process.  (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: No extra money needs to be paid by you other than the iPhone development program fee which you already have done.  Earnings come via the usual channel once a month

Answer (score 1):

You must be enrolled in the iOS Developer Program to join the iAd Network. Members need to do the following:

```
* Agree to the Developer Advertising Services Agreement in iTunes Connect.
* Set up your banking and tax information if you don’t have a paid app on the App Store.
* Enable your app for iAd ads in the Manage Your Applications module within iTunes Connect.
* Set up your iAd preferences in the iAd Network module within iTunes Connect.
```